# Angular 2 problems with directive input / output

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I cannot bind variables input / outputs. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
<p [timeDelta]="'2016-09-20 00:00:00'">{{delta}}</p>
```

Here is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, Renderer, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[timeDelta]' })
export class TimeDeltaDirective {
    @Input('timeDelta') myDate: string;
    @Output() delta: string;

    constructor(renderer: Renderer, el: ElementRef) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.myDate);
        this.delta = (this.myDate);
    }
}
```

The first console.log(this) returns correct value:

- TimeDeltaDirective object {delta: undefined, myDate: "2016-09-20 00:00:00"}

The second one returns: undefined

But why? A microsecond before it outputs the whole object with myDate in it, but while accessing this.myDate it returns undefined.

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Inputs()` are not yet assigned when the `constructor()` is executed.

Use `ngOnInit` hook instead of constructor

```
  constructor(renderer: Renderer, el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.myDate);
    this.delta = (this.myDate);
  }
```

```
constructor(renderer: Renderer, el: ElementRef) {}

ngOnChanges(...) {
  // inputs are updated
}

ngOnInit() {
  // executes after ngOnChanges was called the first time
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.myDate);
  this.delta = (this.myDate);
}
```